# Debugging hhvm segmentation faults

Tags: hhvm

How can I debug a segmentation fault when running php script with hhvm? When I run it, I get:

```
Core dumped: Segmentation fault
Segmentation fault
```

In stacktrace I get that it error when I call a method of the same object.

Is there any code analyzer that might tell me wrong php code or somehow to get more verbose on errors or stack trace?

When I use

```
    $r = mysql_query($sql, $link); //crashes
    $r = mysql_query($sql); //does not crash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Debug build

To get a better understanding of the crash, you need to build HHVM for debug.

This can be done by adding `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to your `cmake`.

More info can be found here:
https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Reporting-Crashes

---

#### Stack trace

You may also find a trace named `stacktrace.[number].log` in the `/tmp` directory.

If after inspecting the stack trace you realise that the bug is not on your side, it is best to submit a new issue here:
https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues

---

#### Better logging

Once the issue is not a seg fault, you can get more out of your logging.

[Here is how my `hhvm.hdf` log section looks like](https://gist.github.com/sinaa/020e168d15d7c56ecf31).

Comment: I did analyze the stack trace. Unfortunately I do not know how to interpret those info & also do not know how can I decide if the bug is on my side.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace? Also a snippet of the code would also be helpful. I don't think there is any automated tool that decides whether a bug is on your side or not. If the code seems to be rather trivial and it runs fine on php 5.5, then it is possibly due to a bug in hhvm.

Comment: For now, i can share stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/UHT6cLFp. I will try to create a code that reproduces the same error

Comment: Ok, are you also running the latest version of hhvm? (3.0.1) There was a recent issue with mysqli_fetch_assoc on version 3 (but that wasn't resulting in a seg fault). https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2218

Comment: I am using, HipHop VM 3.0.0-dev (rel). Also, I am using mysql_ and not mysqli_. Actually my problems gets around using $link that is returrned by mysql_connect(). I updated my question

Comment: As a heads up, mysql_query is deprecated as of php 5.5. You should use mysqli or PDO. Additionally, the `link` as far as I know is not mandatory (if a link is already established, it will use that).

Comment: True, is not mandatory, but I use 2 different connection in my code, so I need that. As curiosity, the line that crashes  gives "Notice: Array to string conversion in". I'll try to change mysqli

Comment: It is almost impossible to provide any further help without a larger snippet of the code and the reported errors. It might be the case that mysql_query is using a `string` $link, and due to a type mismatch it is crashing. but I am not sure how that can be happening without the rest of the code.

Comment: I know. I'll work on it and came back with a feedback. Another problem might be that mysqli_query has an reveresed order of parameters. Thank you for all help.